# What is used for serialization of wcf service soapformatter or xml serialzer or datacontract serializer

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, serialization

I am totally confused about what serialization is used for wcf web  services. Soap object is used for transmitting data from server to client and vice versa.

Is it using soap formatter or xml serializer? Also second question is there is also datacontract serializer, why it is meant for? I warm up google so many times but could not find appropriate answer. Please assist me here in this regard. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WCF uses DataContract serialization. And so, the answer to your second question is yes, there is a data contract serializer.

1. Here is a link to MSDN about DataContract serialization:
   [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. This link describes how to use the DataContract attribute - this marks a class for data contract serialization.
   [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
3. This link describes how to use the DataMember attribute - this marks a property/field for data contract serialization
   [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
4. Finally, here is a link to show you how to create a class with simple data contract serialization:
   [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733811(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733811%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response but this only gives information about datacontract.

Comment: This answers: I am totally confused about what serialization is used for wcf web services. The serialization used is DataContract serialization. It is an xml serializer - do these links help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073(v=vs.110).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730035(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: and what if anybody does not used class with DataContract attribute and use only Message contract

Comment: I think I see what you are getting at. For the most part, using DataContract serialization will simplify your work. Only if you need some special, custom SOAP headers or special security do you need to use Message Contracting. Message contracting let's you have more control over the serialization. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Wcf data,message travelled by the SOAP message. If there is a SOAP message then there should be SOAP formatter(I think). OR it is done by xml or datacontract serializer for serialization .So How SOAP message is created. I mean by which formatter. I think answer of this question may solve my twist.